# How to change the ip address of phpmyadmin MySQL?

Tags: php, database

I change the ip address of my apache in my xampp but i cannot connect to my MySQL. I think the problem is that my apache is not on the same network in my database. My apache is on 192.168.1.10. while my MySQL is on 127.0.0.1. Please help me. I don't know what to do. Thankyou.

Comment: Are you working on `localhost` or `server`?

Comment: I'm working on Server

Answer (score 6):

search for `config.inc.php` in phpmyadmin folder

and change this

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`

Comment: I do it but I cannot access my phpMyAdmin now. what should i do?

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1. This is the message: #1130 - Host 'Jemzz' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server. Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.  phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: either the host is incorrect, or you don't allow remote connections on the machine that hosts the sql server

Answer (score 0):

For the version of phpmyadmin I had installed (4.6.6) the configuration file was at

> /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php

It looks like:

```
<?php
##
## database access settings in php format
## automatically generated from /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
## by /usr/sbin/dbconfig-generate-include
##
## by default this file is managed via ucf, so you shouldn't have to
## worry about manual changes being silently discarded.  *however*,
## you'll probably also want to edit the configuration file mentioned
## above too.
##
$dbuser='phpmyadmin';
$dbpass='myrealpassword';
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
$dbserver='localhost';
$dbport='3306';
$dbtype='mysql';
```

And then obviously you just change `dbserver` to `127.0.0.1` . This is especially useful if you've turned of mysql name resolution by setting `skip-name-resolve=1` in the mysql configuration file

> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf