# IIS doesn't work on localhost, how to solve?

Tags: iis, phpmyadmin, localhost, iis-10

Looks like localhost is not working. For this example I will use `192.192.92.92` as my ip address!

Starting by the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host`:

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

`IIS binding`:

```
Type: http
IP address: All Unasigned (there is no 127.0.0.1 or localhost in the list)
Port: 80
hostName: -blank-
```

When I start the server and click browse in ISS it opens the browser with the following error:

[image: DEMO 1]

The strange thing with this is that it works perfectly fine with a custom host name!

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host`:

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

192.192.92.92 myCustomHostName.com
```

`IIS binding`:

```
Type: http
IP address: 192.192.92.92
Port: 80
hostName: myCustomHostName.com
```

[image: DEMO 2]

---

My main objective is to figure out how to find a way to run the IIS app on the localhost again. It used to work before, but I think uninstalling APACHEE - XAMPP confused everything in IIS and now there is no 127.0.0.1!

Stuff I have tried and didn't work for me:

Youtube:

1. [Error || PhpMyAdmin || Login AllowNoPassword Error - Solved-](https://youtu.be/J-zV6HFGCwk)
2. [How to Restrict access to the phpMyAdmin by IP Address](https://youtu.be/iV-5E4d34To)
3. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BX57ooAulsY](https://youtu.be/BX57ooAulsY)
4. [How To Change User Password In phpMyAdmin If You're Locked Out Of Your Site | WP Learning Lab](https://youtu.be/4hGUso4Ktok)
5. [Error || PhpMyAdmin || Login AllowNoPassword Error - Solved-](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-zV6HFGCwk)
6. [access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes or no)](https://youtu.be/lP1UopbhiOo)

SO:

1. [Setting up 'localhost' equivalent bindings with IIS7](https://serverfault.com/questions/61535/setting-up-localhost-equivalent-bindings-with-iis7)
2. [Getting error mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory when i try to access my project on live server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928109/getting-error-mysqlireal-connect-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-wh)
3. [How to change the ip address of phpmyadmin MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541927/how-to-change-the-ip-address-of-phpmyadmin-mysql)

Comment: Remove other settings in the Hosts file. there is no need to specify localhost to correspond the 127.0.0.1 address.
What about typing the 127.0.0.1 IP address in the browser address bar?

Comment: I tried removing everything from hosts, reset the bindings to "all unasigned" and blank host name. I tried running `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` on the browser but neither work for me! Although `192.192.92.92` seems to be working fine!

Comment: I have also tried changing the ip address to `127.0.0.1` in the bindings and also didn't work! I tried it with and without the hosts

Comment: Can you Ping Localhost/127.0.0.1 successfully? If it indeed works, this demonstrates local NIC/Network driver has no problem. I suspect there is something wrong with the application. please try to create a new website in the IIS and re-set up the Http binding.

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou Did you solve this, eventually?